# Unable to debug Typescript in VSCode

Tags: debugging, typescript, visual-studio-code

Here is my launch.json

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "name": "Launch Server",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server/src/app.ts",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "dev"
            },
            "skipFiles": [
                "node_modules/**/*.js"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/dist/server/src/*.js"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "console": "internalConsole"
        },
```

My source folder:

[image]

My dist folder:

[image]

The error I get is:

```
Cannot launch program '/Dev/myapp/server/src/app.ts'; setting the 'outFiles' attribute might help.
```

If I change the "program" property to ""program": "${workspaceRoot}/dist/server/src/app.js", it works but I'm then debugging the transpiled javascript and not the typescript.  Obviously the transpiling with .map files is working, what is wrong?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "web",
    "dist",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `src` folder in your configuration:

```
"outFiles": [
    "${workspaceRoot}/dist/server/src/*.js"
],
```

Also set your `mapRoot` in `tsconfig.json` to `./dist/`. Currently it will search your `./server/src` folder for sourcemaps instead of `./dist`

Comment: sorry not sure how that was missing at first.. even with the /src folder in outfiles I get the same error

Comment: Can you post your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Why is `mapRoot` set to `./` in `tsconfig.json`. Your sourcemaps are in `disc/server/src/` right?

Comment: It depends, there are 4 apps sharing the same tsconfig.. all output to dist/{appName}/src

Comment: Then perhaps it should be set to `./dist/`? Currently it will search your `./server/src` folder for sourcemaps instead of `dist`.

Comment: that was it!  debugging typescript works now!  if you want to edit this answer I'll select it as the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had in launch.json

```
"program": "${file}"
```

Which obviously tried to run the ts file in node, when hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>
when changing it to

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.js"
```

allows me to run both active ts and js files...

also launch tsc -watch build task to get js file compiled on the fly